# How to remove an edge connection to a vertex in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb, vertex, orientdb2.2

I created an `HasAddress` `edge` between an `User` and an `Address` `vertex`.

If I remove the `HasAddress` `edge`, the `User` `vertex` still shows the `HasAddress` connection, just empty.

[image]

Any way of removing it? Is this just a GUI thing?

this doesn't seem to work `UPDATE User REMOVE HasAddress`

Comment: Hi, I think it's a GUI thing. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not properly a GUI thing, but you can ignore it.

When you create an edge and connect it to a vertex, OrientDB creates a collection of links (a RIDBAG) as a property of the vertex. When you delete edges, the edge pointer is removed from the collection, but the collection itself is not removed.

If you really don't like that, you can run an

```
UPDATE User REMOVE in_HasAddress 

/* or out_HasAddress if you want to remove the outgoing edges collection */
```

but PLEASE, make sure that the collections are EMPTY, otherwise you will break the graph consistency (you are using a document API to manipulate the graph).

My advice is to avoid it in general.

Comment: Thanks. I do prefer if `HasAddress` wasn't there if the edge was removed.. It's easier to see what link is used or not. For example, the `out_HasAddress` is not used, but `out_HasPhone` is used, even though has a few empty entrees. Never the less, your query works.

Comment: use `WHERE` clause when u have more than one record.